# Start TinyOS programming and simulation in Windows

Tags: cygwin, rpm, tinyos, nesc

I want to start programming nesC for wireless sensor network on TinyOS in Windows environment. So far, I installed Cygwin terminal, and don't know how to install those packages. 
To install the package, the command is like " rpm ***" but not sun command in Cygwin, it's Linux based.  Is there any one can help?

Answer (score 3):

So if you want to install TinyOS in windows, the simplest way is to run the virtual machine for windows, the steps could be found here:

http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Use_TinyOS_in_a_virtual_machine

Comment: It might make sense to copy and paste the steps (since they are simple and few) to your answer directly (but keep the external link).

Answer (score 1):

You can try

http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Installing_TinyOS

but I would recommend to use TinyOS in Linux.